# time difference in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: php

I want to get time difference in HH:MM:SS format below is the code

if time diff in seconds it should display  l
like 00:00:35
In minutes :00:30:35
In Hrs :01:30:35

```
$start_date = new DateTime($var1[TIME]);
$end_date = new DateTime($var2[TIME]);
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
$seconds = $interval->format('%s');
echo $diff = $hours * 60 + $minutes + $seconds;
```

Comment: Read up on the php date() function to understand how DateTime::format works. http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$hours   = $interval->format('%H'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%I');
$seconds = $interval->format('%S');
```

and concat both three for one variable

or use  `$interval->format('%H:%I:%S')` for single output

```
//output 00:30:35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime() for time calculation. Here is an example:

```
$time1 = strtotime('10:55:59');<br>
$time2 = strtotime('10:56:00');<br>
$diff = $time2 - $time1;<br>
echo 'Time 1: '.date('H:i:s', $time1).'\n';<br>
echo 'Time 2: '.date('H:i:s', $time2).'\n';

if($diff){<br>
    echo 'Diff: '.date('H:i:s', $diff);<br>
}else{<br>
    echo 'No Diff.';<br>
}<br>
```

Output:

```
Time 1: 09:00:59<br>
Time 2: 09:01:00<br>
Diff: 00:00:01
```

Comment: Hey Vinod, thank you for the answer, I have a problem, I have $time1= "00:00:00"  and $time2= "00:00:07", after using your way I get  "01:00:07" instead of "00:00:07" , do you know why ?