# Get the time difference in H:mm:ss format

Tags: php

I am trying to find the time difference between two time values in the format `H:mm:ss` using PHP.

When I tried with the following code, I'm getting the difference `01:00:20` instead of `00:00:20`. What's wrong with my code?

```
$start_time = strtotime("0:17:14");
$end_time = strtotime("0:17:34");
$diff = $end_time - $start_time;
echo date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

Comment: Exact Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22475091/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa you can add extra duplicates to the list via the ["edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/47193446/edit) link :)

Comment: @Phil I've never done that before / don't know how to do that / don't see what you are suggesting.  Do I have this ability?  Do I need a gold PHP badge or something?

Comment: @mickmackusa oh, must be a higher-rep privilege. I've added your link into the list at the top

Comment: @Phil Good on ya.  I guess I'll need to to wait until I am more grown up to edit the list.  Will this be insta-deleted as exact duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$diff` variable is not a timestamp, it's a duration/interval. The `date()` function is intended to format timestamps, and won't properly handle intervals like you're expecting.

Instead, try using the `DateTime` class to read your timestamps, and turn the difference between them into a `DateInterval` using `DateTime::diff()`. You can then use `DateInterval::format` to get the output you want.

Something like this should work:

```
$start_time = new DateTime("0:17:14");
$end_time = new DateTime("0:17:34");
$diff = $end_time->diff($start_time);
echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```